# Spatial Index for lat/lng on JSONB column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table with thousands of records with a JSONB column that has a location (geometry) as a point. I am able to select points within a bounding box using this query.

```
 SELECT
    url,
    ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(keywords ->> 'lat_lng'::text))
FROM
    photos
WHERE
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(keywords ->> 'lat_lng'::text) && ST_MakeEnvelope(-74.494259, 39.486874, -74.774259 , 39.786874, 4326);
```

Example of keywords column on my table:

```
{"lat_lng": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ["-74.218001", "40.107786"]}, "name": "test_name"}
```

I know that I can add a spatial index to speed up my queries like so, but the problem is that i dont have a lat_lng column, I have a JSONB column with geometry points. (this is just an example on how to add spatial index)

```
CREATE INDEX places_lat_lng_idx ON places USING gist(lat_lng);
```

So I did added this as an index instead:

```
CREATE INDEX photos_lat_lng_idx ON photos USING GIST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(keywords ->> 'lat_lng'::text));
```

I was able to create that without error and run explain on my query which doesn't do a sequential scan anymore and noticably faster. 
On 10k rows I am getting this without the index on the JSONB column :

[image]

And with the index on the JSONB, I get this: 
[image]

My question is, Am I right to assume that applying the index on the JSONB column worked?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."photos" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('photos_id_seq'::regclass),
    "url" varchar,
    "created_at" int4,
    "deleted_at" int4,
    "keywords" jsonb,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Postgres version:  11.7

Postgis version: 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: That is called a functional index and should have worked as expected; it's over one order of magnitude faster! Try updating table stats; run 'VACUUM ANALYZE photos;` and check the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` again. You may get off Heap or Bitmap Scans, but this depends on the table.

Comment: on a side note, coordinates should be expresses as longitude first, then latitude.

Comment: @geozelot thanks for this confirmation! I did vacuum analyze but still giving my heap or bitmap scans, i think its fine for now i still get way faster queries!! If you make your comment an answer ill gladly accept it :)

Comment: @JGH Thanks for your comment! but which part are you referring to?

Comment: @ET2019 your variable is named `lat_long`, which is the opposite. If you data is in antartica, it is a naming issue. If you data is in the USA, it is a naming + coordinates swap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **correctly** creating a functional (spatial) index right there, and it shows: one order of magnitude less execution time.

There may be subtle ways to coerce the planner to go for a more direct index lookup, but, assuming your data structure, none will have an improvement as significant to execution time as what you get from the current setup.